# Can't use two dimensional object return values from web service

Tags: java, web-services, object, arraylist

I have the following web service:

```
 @WebMethod(operationName = "getCaseTypeNamesAndIDs")
 public Object [][] getCaseTypeNamesAndIDs() {
    Object [][] nameIDs;
    int [] ids;

    ids = LOKmeth.getAllCaseTypes();
    nameIDs = new Object [ids.length][2];

    for(int ct = 0; ct < ids.length; ct++ )
    {
        nameIDs[ct][0] = LOKmeth.getCaseTypeName(ids[ct]);
    }

    for(int ct = 0; ct < ids.length; ct++ )
    {
        nameIDs[ct][1] = ids[ct];
    }

    return nameIDs;
}
```

It is supposed to fill the first dimension with "case type" names in form of strings and the second dimension with "case type" IDs made out of ints.

When I test the web service it outputs:

**Method returned**

```
java.util.List : "[net.java.dev.jaxb.array.AnyTypeArray@4a0cf658, net.java.dev.jaxb.array.AnyTypeArray@19013163, net.java.dev.jaxb.array.AnyTypeArray@1d516768]"
```

**SOAP Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getCaseTypeNamesAndIDsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://LOK_WS/">
            <return>
                <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Bugg</item>
                <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:int">3</item>
            </return>
            <return>
                <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Felrapport</item>
                <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:int">1</item>
            </return>
            <return>
                <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Printer on fire</item>
                <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:int">2</item>
            </return>
        </ns2:getCaseTypeNamesAndIDsResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I figure that the method return is memory references to arrays.

The SOAP response contains the right data.

***My problem is the following:***
How do I extract the data in my jsp pages?

I've tried to do something like the following (with some variations):

```
<%
try 
{
    lok_ws.CaseManagementWs_Service service = new lok_ws.CaseManagementWs_Service();
    lok_ws.CaseManagementWs port = service.getCaseManagementWsPort();

    java.util.List<net.java.dev.jaxb.array.AnyTypeArray> caseTypeNames = null;

    caseTypeNames = port.getCaseTypeNamesAndIDs();

    Object[][] result = new Object[1][];
    result[0] = caseTypeNames.toArray();

    out.println("<option value=\"\">");
    out.println(result[0][0].toString());
    out.println("</option>");
} catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
```

I read the [A java.lang.ClassCastException while accessing web service method written in java. jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716926/a-java-lang-classcastexception-while-accessing-web-service-method-written-in-jav) and tried to follow his solution but it didn't help.

What do I have to do to use the references the method gives me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your web-service should rather return an a list of application-specific objects instead of a plain 2-dim array.
Your web-service response contains a list of "case type" objects that contain string and int fields.
So it would be better to create (on web-service side) a class similar to this :

```
class CaseType {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  // getters, setters
}
```

And the web-service should basically return a list of CaseType objects (`List<CaseType>`) . Not only it will solve your web-service problems, but it will also improve general design, because using explicit and named classes is self-documenting and easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I was expecting 2 dim array. Luckily my friend helped me!

This is my solution:

```
StringArray[] user = response.get_return();

for(int i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
    String[] a = user[i].getItem();

    for(String c:a)
        System.out.println(c);
}
```